# Setting proxy to Android Emulator

Tags: android

I'm having a problem to surf internet on my Emulator, wich is targeting Google API8.I followed all the instructions I have read, setting the proxy in MobileNetworks-->APN--->....,etc, and doesn`t work. If I remove the proxy, the browser navigates locally, and if I have the proxy configured  it doesn't even navigate locally.
I tested the same coonfiguration on an emulator targeting API16 and **did work**!!!!(local and on the Internet), so please how can I solve this.Any help will be appreciated.
PD: I tested using -dns-server x.x.x.x too and happens the same.

Answer (score 0):

Emulator uses the internet connection from the host computer where it's installed.

If the host computer doesn't need any special configuration to access internet (proxy, etc.), then your emulator doesn't need it either.

Only if your computer needs a proxy configuration (or other), you will need to replicate it in the emulator.

Regards.